# How to sew a rounded neckline on a men's thobe?

Tags: sewing, sewing-machine, pattern-drafting, measurements, clothing-fitting

[image: Text]
i wanted to know the pattern for sewing the rounded neck of this mens thobe, can someone send me a pattern or give me some clue about it, thanks in regard,

Comment: Hi Faiza, welcome to Arts & Crafts! We expect some effort on behalf of the person asking questions, and requests for finding things (like patterns) are off-topic here (and on the rest of the network). Can you tell us what you have tried or found so far? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you search for "standing collar" and maybe look at some instructional videos, you should be able to figure it out. There's only a very limited number of ways how to attatch collars, so most are very similar.